# Plotting separate histograms using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to plot a different histogram for every polymer length, each in a separate window.

This is what I'm getting - 3 histograms on top of each other in a single window
[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for polymer_length in polymer_lengths:
with open('radii_{0}d_N{1}_l{2}.txt'.format(int(dim), polymer_length, int(monomer_length))) as radii_file:
    radii_raw = radii_file.readlines()
    nice_radii = []
    for ele in radii_raw[1:]:
        nice_radii.append(float(ele))

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

plt.hist(nice_radii, bins=25, rwidth=0.95)

plt.title('Histogram for Polymer length {} with monomer length {}, in {}D'.format(polymer_length, int(monomer_length), int(dim)))
plt.xlabel('Radius')
plt.ylabel('Number of Radii')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Notes:

- This is just a section of the program. I have different `.txt` file each containing every radius the program have ever calculated. Every file needs to be distinguished by the polymer parameters, hence the separate histograms.

Edit:

Thanks to tmdavison I've changed the code to

```
plt.title('Histogram for Polymer length {} with monomer length {}, in {}D'.format(polymer_length, int(monomer_length), int(dim)))
plt.xlabel('Radius')
plt.ylabel('Number of Radii')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.figure()
```

Now I indeed get separate histograms but it draws an additional empty figure.

Comment: create a new figure with `plt.figure()` before plotting the second and third histograms

Comment: Or, better yet, use the matplotlib object-oriented approach to more easily keep track of what is being plotted on each of your figures: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#the-object-oriented-interface-and-the-pyplot-interface

Comment: Thank you, I've added the command and removed the ```plt.show()```, it works well but now it draws an a additional empty figure.

Comment: `plt.figure` should be before `plt.hist`

Comment: use the plt.figure() before plotting each figure. not after

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody who commented. The answer is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for polymer_length in polymer_lengths:
with open('radii_{0}d_N{1}_l{2}.txt'.format(int(dim), polymer_length, int(monomer_length))) as radii_file:
    radii_raw = radii_file.readlines()
    nice_radii = []
    for ele in radii_raw[1:]:
        nice_radii.append(float(ele))

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.figure() #<------
plt.hist(nice_radii, bins=25, rwidth=0.95)

plt.title('Histogram for Polymer length {} with monomer length {}, in {}D'.format(polymer_length, int(monomer_length), int(dim)))
plt.xlabel('Radius')
plt.ylabel('Number of Radii')

plt.tight_layout()
```